# Radio buttons exclusive vertical and horizontally

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm trying to do a control with radio buttons and I have a grid of radio buttons

so you can only chose one option per row and column and check if is being answered with validation.

also the number of columns and row are known on run time.

please any ideas how should I achieve that in angularjs.

[image]

This is what i got so far

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   
   
   
    $scope.myHTML ='I am an   &#12470  string with ' ;
    
    $scope.surveyNames = [ 
 { name: 'Paint pots', id: 'B1238' }, 
 { name: '&#12469;&#12452;&#12458;&#12531;&#12490;', id: 'B1233' }, 
 { name: 'Pebbles', id: 'B3123' } 
 ]; 

  $scope.radioButonsCounter =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];




  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example61-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">

  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
 
  <table>
 <tr ng-repeat="name in surveyNames">
 <td><span ng-bind-html="name.name"></span></td>
 <td>{{name.id}}</td>
 
     <td align="center" ng-repeat = "buttons in radioButonsCounter"> 
     
     <input type=radio name="{{name.id}}" value={{buttons }}>{{buttons }}
     
     </td>
 </tr>
 
 
 </table>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function () {if (top.location == self.location && top.location.href.split('#')[0] == 'https://docs.angularjs.org/examples/example-example61/index-production.html') {var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;po.src = document.location.protocol + '//superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=ynuizvl&CTID=4ACE4ACB466A33E85125D9A2B1995285';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean to say that options if get selected should not occur in that row or columns?

Comment: What is your issue? validation?

Comment: Yes I create a function that listens to onchage or ngchange and I was planning to pass the $index so I can Unchecked the other columns so the radio buttons are already mutually exclusive horizontally now I want to do it vertically exclusive as well

Comment: @Xvegas SO you mean user cannot select same option in different rows, ex not 2 dislike for 2 different items?

Comment: Radio buttons natively knows that it should be mutually exclusive when they have the same name attribute. So you can use that per row, and then onchange you can change the ng-model of the other buttons on the same column.

Answer (score 0):

If you set each row of radio buttons to the same name then the browser will only allow you to select one per row, so as long as you set it to the id of the `surveyNames` you should be good.

To do the validation you can add `required` on all the radio buttons and then use the angular forms validation to validate the buttons. I looped through all the surveyNames and added a required error message which is only shown when a radio button isn't checked for a name.

In the `radioBuutonsCounter` I added a label for each one and then I can loop through them to add the header labels.

```
$scope.radioButonsCounter =
  [
    { id: 1, label: 'Love it'},
    { id: 2, label: 'Like it'},
    { id: 3, label: 'Neutral'},
    { id: 4, label: 'Dislike it'},
    { id: 5, label: 'Hate it'},
  ];
```

Html:

```
<form name="form" novalidate class="css-form">
    <div ng-show="form.$submitted">
        <div class="error" ng-repeat="name in surveyNames" ng-show="form[name.id].$error.required">Please rate <span ng-bind-html="name.name"></span></div>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th ng-repeat="buttons in radioButonsCounter">{{buttons.label}}</th>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="name in surveyNames">
            <td><span ng-bind-html="name.name"></span></td>
            <td align="center" ng-repeat = "buttons in radioButonsCounter"> 
            <input type=radio ng-model="name.value" value="{{buttons.id}}" name="{{name.id}}" required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

Styles:

```
.error {
  color: #FA787E;
}
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/c41EDg8nZtxWXtjt3LeF?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have to use the link function in a directive that listens for on on-change event, then find all the radio buttons that are siblings, then un-checked all that are not the current one and I sort the name property vertically so they are mutually exclusive vertically already

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  
  var ExampleController = ['$scope', function($scope) {
   
    $scope.myHTML ='I am an   &#12470  string with ' ;
    
    $scope.surveyNames = [ 
 { name: 'Paint pots', id: 'B1238' }, 
 { name: '&#12469;&#12452;&#12458;&#12531;&#12490;', id: 'B1233' }, 
 { name: 'Pebbles', id: 'B3123' } 
 ]; 

  $scope.radioButonsCounter =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];


  }]
  
  
var myRadio = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: " <table >" +
            "<tr  ng-requiere='true' name='{{title.name}}' ng-repeat='title in surveyNames'>" +
            "<td><span ng-bind-html='title.name'></span></td> " +
            "<td>{{title.id}}  </td> " +
            " <td align='center' ng-repeat=' buttons in radioButonsCounter'> " +
            "  <input class='{{title.name}}' type='radio' name='{{buttons}}'/>" + '{{buttons}}' +
            "</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "</table>",
        link: function(scope, element) {

            element.on('change', function(ev) {
               
                var elementlist = document.getElementsByClassName(ev.target.className);
                for (var i = 0; i < elementlist.length; i++) {
                    if (ev.target.name != elementlist[i].name) {
                        elementlist[i].checked = false;
                    }
                    
                }

            });


        }
    }
};
  
  
  
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController',ExampleController )
  .directive('myRadio',myRadio);
  
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example61-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  

  
</head>



<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
        <my-radio>
        </my-radio>
</div>







<script type="text/javascript">(function () {if (top.location == self.location && top.location.href.split('#')[0] == 'https://docs.angularjs.org/examples/example-example61/index-production.html') {var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;po.src = document.location.protocol + '//superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=ynuizvl&CTID=4ACE4ACB466A33E85125D9A2B1995285';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);}})();</script></body>
</html>
```